# how to configure jest with webpack, node_modules and scss

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs

## Update: edited jest config in package.json to include identity-obj-proxy and added transform-es2015-modules-commonjs to .babelrc

Trying to setup jest and enzyme to run unit tests on a React.js project.  This configuration setting works fine as long as I'm not requiring a node_module in the target component. But if the component I want to test imports a node_module that itself imports a scss file it throws this error:

```js
import('../../scss/bulkAction.scss');
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

This is my jest config file:

```js
"jest": {
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/(node_modules)"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "jsx"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/app/_tests_/config/fileMock.js",
          "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/app/_tests_/config/scssTransform.js",
    "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|json)$)": "<rootDir>/app/_tests_/config/fileTransform.js"
  }
},
```

this is my .babelrc file

```js
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}], "react", "stage-0"],
  "env": {
    "start": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried multiple different configurations and have been reading the docs for quite awhile and haven't been able to solve this problem. I'm hoping someone can help!

Note about our file structure:

`/WebApps/ProjectName/ProjectFolder/app`

`/WebApps/ProjectName/ProjectFolder/package.json`
`/WebApps/ProjectName/ProjectFolder/.babelrc`
`/WebApps/ProjectName/ProjectFolder/node_modules`

I add this just incase the file pathing of the  may be part of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed probably `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` babel plugin.

Add this to your `.babelrc`

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}]
  ],

  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to install this plugin before using:

```
babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs --save-dev
```

When you run your tests with `jest`, it set the environment as `test` by default.

In my project I use also `identity-obj-proxy`, like:

```
// jest.config.json
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
}
```

Also, first install it before using:

```
npm install --save-dev identity-obj-proxy
```

I highly recommend reading the page from official jest documentation about integration jest with webpack.

- https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html#mocking-css-modules
- https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html#using-with-webpack-2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately this didn't resolve my problem. I'll post my updated webpack jest config and .babelrc file above in case you have any other ideas.

Comment: interestingly if I remove ```"\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"``` jest no longer throws the ```unexpected import``` error, and instead chokes on a the ```.``` before a css class. For example: ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token . :: .Flex {} ```

Comment: Try don't repeat `presets: [...]` in `env.test` in `.babelrc`, so it should be https://jsfiddle.net/6knazLxd/ I'm pretty sure that you need to have disabled modules like `["es2015", {"modules": false}]`